# Browser opening error in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (LXDE) running through Linux Deploy

Tags: 18.04, android, vnc, lxde

Linux deploy is an android app which runs linux on android.

I installed linux deploy, installed LXDE version of Ubuntu 18.04LTS through it. I access it through a VNC viewer. Everything runs fine except for the inbuilt browser present in it. Whenever I tap on browser icon, there is an error message stating that

**"Invalid desktop entry file
'/usr/share/applications/lxde-x-www-browser.desktop' "**

I tried reinstalling the whole thing, nothing works.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Does the file exist? What does the file contain?

Comment: Yes..it is a disc image file which got installed in my sd card

Comment: I mean `/usr/share/applications/lxde-x-www-browser.desktop`. The system is telling you that a file is invalid. Check, and edit the question to include your findings.